# WordPress: How get most view post posted in last 24 hours

Tags: wordpress

I have this query to get most post views.

I want to retrieve top 3 most viewed topic which are posted in last 24 hours. If the website gets less than 3 topics from last 24 hours it has to retrive the remaining most viewed topics from the previous day.

```
<?php   

    $today = getdate();
    $args = array(
        'meta_key'          => 'wpb_post_views_count',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'posts_per_page'    => 3,
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'date_query'        => array(
            array(
                'year'  => $today['year'],
                'month' => $today['mon'],
                'day'   => $today['mday']
            )
        )
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
```

How can do that ?

Comment: i need get top post views last 24 hours

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that. But what have you already tried which does not work or only work in parts or sth. like that. We need more information: How do you count visitors (or do you mean "page hits"?), how do you save the data for the last 24 hours, are you counting daywise or really only the last 24 hour... There is so much left unanswered that nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => '24 hours ago'
        )
    )
);
$arr_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 
if ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $arr_posts->have_posts() ) :
    $arr_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        </a>
        <?php wpb_get_post_views(get_the_ID()); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

By writing the above code you can retrieve the most viewed posts from the last 24 hours.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

You can change the size of the thumbnail (Featured Image) according to your own requirement. Visit this site for reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score -2):

```
 $args = array('orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',"posts_per_page"=> 3, 'date_query'=> array( 'hour'=> 0,));   
 $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
 while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```